# CSS selection of first column of first row of a table (excluding nested tables)

Tags: css

I'm having difficulty with CSS selectors and I hope someone can perhaps help me out here.

I have some HTML that looks like so:

```
<table class=myTable>
   <tr>
      <td>this is the td of interest</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <table>
            <tr><td>I don't want this td!</td></tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to apply a background image to the FIRST td of the FIRST tr. So I tried the following:

```
table.myTable tr:first-child td:first-child {
    background-image: url(someUrl.gif);
}
```

But this is also finding the first td of the first tr of the nested table. I've tried different combinations with > and +, but no luck. Anyone have any ideas?

Note: I'm aiming for a solution that is compatible with IE7+.

Comment: You shouldn't use nested tables at all. No matter for what purpose.

Comment: I agree for websites but I still use tables for HTML email

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The selector you need is

```
table.myTable > tbody > tr:first-child > td:first-child
```

There is an implicit TBODY element in there, even though you don't have it in the code.

Comment: Note if you have a table cell with a rowspan of 2, the next row will hit this on the indented table cell (or 2nd column).

Comment: worth pointing out that if you set a set a background color for the column, it will apply to tables within that column, unless overridden.

Answer (score 5):

```
table.myTable > tr:first-child > td:first-child
```

The > means the tr that is a direct child of table

Comment: This didn't work for me. I think `> tbody` is required.

Answer (score 4):

Not that speed is really a problem for the average website in this day and age, but, worth a note.

tags are slower to find than classes and classes are slower to find than id's.

So for simplicity and speed, how about just assigning an id to the element in question and applying a style to the id?

Comment: I'm working with an application that allows for custom css, but I don't own/have access to the code.

Comment: Ah ok, well im glad you found your answer above.

Answer (score 4):

This work for me:

`table.myClass > tbody:first-of-type > tr > td:first-child`

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 4):

```
table.myTable  > tbody tr > td:first-child
```

For first column.

Comment: please add more comments to better explain your solution

Comment: Selects all cells in the first column, other examples only selects the first cell of the first line ( which off-course, can be useful )

Answer (score 1):

> table.myTable > tr:first-child > td:first-child

This code is difficult to support. Try the following instead:

```
<table class="myTable">
   <tr>
      <td class="verySpecialCell">this is the td of interest</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <table>
            <tr><td>I don't want this td!</td></tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

or even

```
<table class=myTable>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div class="verySpecialContent">
            this is the td of interest
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <table>
            <tr><td>I don't want this td!</td></tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Be nice; don't be mean.

Answer (score 1):

table.table td:nth-child(1) {text-align: center; font-weight: bold;}

Answer (score 0):

The following code may help you,

**HTML Code:**

```
<table id="myTableId" class="myTableClass">
    <tr>
        <th>S.No</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS Code:**

*Using table id:*

```
table[id="myTableId"] > tr:first-child > th:first-child{
}
```

*Using table class:*

```
table[class="myTableClass"] > tr:first-child > th:first-child{
}
```

or

```
table.myTableClass > tr:first-child > th:first-child{
}
```

or

```
table.myTableClass tr:first-child > th:first-child{
}
```